# Problems parsing XML in Objective - C

Tags: objective-c, xml, xcode, gdataxml

I am currently trying to make a simple "Server Status" app for a game I play, All it needs to do is parse XML from a URL and output the result. I am currently stuck on these errors which I think have something to do with the way I linked/incorporated my GDataXML

See Images for Error(s), Sorry I could post picture directly. Not enough reputation:

Error (1)
Undefined symbols for architecture i386: **"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataXMLDocument", referenced from:** objc-class-ref in ViewController.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Error (2)
Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataXMLDocument", referenced from:   objc-class-ref in ViewController.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: **linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linker can't find object for GDataXML.
Looks like you need build GDataXML and add path where library built to the linker.

Comment: What is the terminal command to do so? For some reason I don't think I am installing GDataXML correctly. When I go to build it, I use:
svn checkout http://gdata-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gdata-objectivec-client-read-only

Comment: When you checked out sources you need to open GData.xcodeproj from Sources folder. When you build it you can setup project as you need (for example, release or debug). After project has built you need add  generated framework into external frameworks for your project.

Answer (score 0):

It might be as you suspect, the class you are trying to use isn't incorporated in your project correctly, or linked to the target correctly. Maybe [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642808/how-to-fix-compile-mach-o-linker-error) will help you more.